# MySQL - Is there a better way to structure one of my table to reduce the amount of columns?

Tags: mysql

I have a (3x3) table on my website which gives the users the option to unlock a car slot, purchase a car and upgrade the car level.
In total I end up with 9 slots, all 9 slots can have different values (car_unlocked (bool), car_level (int), car_type (int)).

my current table : (user_cars)

```
 id (AUTO_INCR) | user_id | car_slot_unlocked01 | car_level01 | car_type01 | car_slot_unlocked02 | car_level02 | car_type02 | car_slot_unlocked03 | car_level03 | car_type03 | car_slot_unlocked04 | car_level04 | car_type04 …
```

And so on until 9. I end up with 29 columns. And then I retrieve the values with the user_id on my website. Values are unique to every user.

How would I go about reducing the columns amount, because if I was to add more rows (4x4) or (5x5) to my website table I would end up with alot more columns in my database.
Do I create different db table and join it if that is even an option?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Repeating groups are almost always a sign of poor database design. You should consider normalizing your table to first normal form.

Comment: Thank you I will read more about database normalization

Comment: I agree with @Honeyboy Wilson. It's difficult to advise you on how to go with the information you're providing, but to begin with maybe you want to set a new 'car_slot_unlocked '  table with id, name, level, and  type columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can give an ID to the cars so you don't need the repeating columns... something like:

```
id | user_id | car_id | car_slow_unlocked | car_level | car_type
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 1 |  001    |  01    |         1         |     3     |    3
 2 |  001    |  02    |         0         |     5     |    2
 3 |  001    |  03    |         0         |     5     |    3
 4 |  001    |  04    |         1         |     6     |    1
 5 |  001    |  05    |         1         |     1     |    1
 6 |  001    |  06    |         0         |     5     |    2
 7 |  001    |  07    |         0         |     5     |    3
 8 |  001    |  08    |         1         |     6     |    1
 9 |  001    |  09    |         1         |     1     |    1
10 |  002    |  01    |         1         |     5     |    3
11 |  002    |  02    |         0         |     3     |    1
12 |  002    |  03    |         1         |     1     |    1
... and so on
```

Comment: In this case each user would have a total of 9 rows.

Comment: You are right this way of doing it is less the amount of columns I currently have. I don't see any other way of doing it because all my car slots have to be declared individually since they can have different values.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to have a think about your data model.  I don't quite understand your business but start with identifying the entities and their attributes outside of any presentation concerns.
e.g.

```
CarInstance (ID, type, unlocked)
CarType(ID, CarID, Level)
User(ID, name)
UserToCar(userID,carID)
```

I doubt those are right but that's the kind of thing you need to be aiming for.  You can then generate your table from that.